# How to install thermostat with plug in heater?

Tags: electrical, heating, thermostat

My house has three electric wall heaters in different rooms used to augment the gas forced air that heats the whole house.

These electric heaters are mounted on the wall, but plug into standard 120v outlets near the heaters. They have a small hot/hotter/hottest dial on the top of the heater but to turn them off they need to be unplugged.

If I wanted to operate these with a standard wall  thermostat, how would I implement that setup?

Comment: You'd have to get a thermostat that worked with line voltages , and is rated for the proper current. Then you'd use the thermostat to switch the receptacle the heater is plugged into.

Comment: Could I connect a thermostat to a product such as this? 

http://www.adafruit.com/products/268 

or this 

http://www.amazon.com/XANTECH-AC1-Controlled-AC-Outlet/dp/B000NU0T62

Comment: Why?  Just get a line voltage thermostat. Unless you want to have a bunch of junk wired together in a big mess, then feel free to rig as much together as you like.

Comment: Don't forget about thermostat placement.  You'll not want the thermostat too close to the heater, or other heat source, or a window, etc.

Comment: The heaters need to be hard wired to be controlled by wall thermostat. Maybe they have that option but I doubt it.  So you either need new heaters or go with Cominterns option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controlled AC outlet you linked to in the comment above seems like overkill unless you were intending to run all of them from one thermostat.  I'd actually recommend putting all of them on individual thermostats so you can keep them in 3 different heating zones.  Not only would this be much cheaper (the relays don't even include the thermostat), but it would be a "plug and play" solution without having to wire all of the signal wires back to the relay.  I'd take a look at something like [these](https://www.google.com/#q=outlet+thermostat&tbm=shop).